# Finding duplicates in a list of a list, and adding their values

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I'm trying to find the top 50 words that occur within three texts of Shakespeare and the ratio of each words occurrance in, macbeth.txt, allswell.txt, and othello.txt. Here is my code so far:

```
def byFreq(pair):
    return pair[1]

def shakespeare():
counts = {}
A = []
for words in ['macbeth.txt','allswell.txt','othello.txt']:
    text = open(words, 'r').read()
    test = text.lower()

    for ch in '!"$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~':
        text = text.replace(ch, ' ')
        words = text.split()

    for w in words:
        counts[w] = counts.get(w, 0) + 1

    items = list(counts.items())
    items.sort()
    items.sort(key=byFreq, reverse = True)

    for i in range(50):
        word, count = items[i]
        count = count / float(len(counts))
        A += [[word, count]]
print A
```

And its output:

```
     >>> shakespeare()
[['the', 0.12929982922664066], ['and', 0.09148572822639668], ['I', 0.08075140278116613], ['of', 0.07684801171017322], ['to', 0.07562820200048792], ['a', 0.05220785557453037], ['you', 0.04415711149060746], ['in', 0.041717492071236886], ['And', 0.04147353012929983], ['my', 0.04147353012929983], ['is', 0.03927787265186631], ['not', 0.03781410100024396], ['that', 0.0358624054647475], ['it', 0.03366674798731398], ['Macb', 0.03342278604537692], ['with', 0.03269090021956575], ['his', 0.03147109050988046], ['be', 0.03025128080019517], ['The', 0.028787509148572824], ['haue', 0.028543547206635766], ['me', 0.027079775555013418], ['your', 0.02683581361307636], ['our', 0.025128080019516955], ['him', 0.021956574774335203], ['Enter', 0.019516955354964626], ['That', 0.019516955354964626], ['for', 0.01927299341302757], ['this', 0.01927299341302757], ['he', 0.018541107587216395], ['To', 0.01780922176140522], ['so', 0.017077335935594046], ['all', 0.0156135642839717], ['What', 0.015369602342034643], ['are', 0.015369602342034643], ['thou', 0.015369602342034643], ['will', 0.015125640400097584], ['Macbeth', 0.014881678458160527], ['thee', 0.014881678458160527], ['But', 0.014637716516223469], ['but', 0.014637716516223469], ['Macd', 0.014149792632349353], ['they', 0.014149792632349353], ['their', 0.013905830690412296], ['we', 0.013905830690412296], ['as', 0.01341790680653818], ['vs', 0.01341790680653818], ['King', 0.013173944864601122], ['on', 0.013173944864601122], ['yet', 0.012198097096852892], ['Rosse', 0.011954135154915833], ['the', 0.15813168261114238], ['I', 0.14279684862127182], ['and', 0.1231007315700619], ['to', 0.10875070343275182], ['of', 0.10481148002250985], ['a', 0.08581879572312887], ['you', 0.08581879572312887], ['my', 0.06992121553179516], ['in', 0.061902082160945414], ['is', 0.05852560495216657], ['not', 0.05486775464265616], ['it', 0.05472706809229038], ['that', 0.05472706809229038], ['his', 0.04727068092290377], ['your', 0.04389420371412493], ['me', 0.043753517163759144], ['be', 0.04305008441193022], ['And', 0.04037703995498031], ['with', 0.038266741699493526], ['him', 0.037703995498030385], ['for', 0.03601575689364097], ['he', 0.03404614518851998], ['The', 0.03137310073157006], ['this', 0.030810354530106922], ['her', 0.029262802476083285], ['will', 0.0291221159257175], ['so', 0.027011817670230726], ['have', 0.02687113111986494], ['our', 0.02687113111986494], ['but', 0.024760832864378166], ['That', 0.02293190770962296], ['PAROLLES', 0.022791221159257174], ['To', 0.021384355655599326], ['all', 0.021384355655599326], ['shall', 0.021102982554867755], ['are', 0.02096229600450197], ['as', 0.02096229600450197], ['thou', 0.02039954980303883], ['Macb', 0.019274057400112548], ['thee', 0.019274057400112548], ['no', 0.01871131119864941], ['But', 0.01842993809791784], ['Enter', 0.01814856499718627], ['BERTRAM', 0.01758581879572313], ['HELENA', 0.01730444569499156], ['we', 0.01730444569499156], ['do', 0.017163759144625774], ['thy', 0.017163759144625774], ['was', 0.01674169949352842], ['haue', 0.016460326392796848], ['I', 0.19463784682531435], ['the', 0.17894627455055595], ['and', 0.1472513769094877], ['to', 0.12989712147978802], ['of', 0.12002494024732412], ['you', 0.1079704873739998], ['a', 0.10339810869791126], ['my', 0.0909279850358516], ['in', 0.07627558973293151], ['not', 0.07159929335965914], ['is', 0.0697287748103502], ['it', 0.0676504208666736], ['that', 0.06733866777512211], ['me', 0.06099968824690845], ['your', 0.0543489556271433], ['And', 0.053205860958121166], ['be', 0.05310194326093734], ['his', 0.05154317780317988], ['with', 0.04769822300737816], ['him', 0.04665904603553985], ['her', 0.04364543281720877], ['for', 0.04322976202847345], ['he', 0.042190585056635144], ['this', 0.04187883196508366], ['will', 0.035332017042502335], ['Iago', 0.03522809934531851], ['so', 0.03356541619037722], ['The', 0.03325366309882573], ['haue', 0.031902733035435935], ['do', 0.03138314454951678], ['but', 0.030240049880494647], ['That', 0.02857736672555336], ['thou', 0.027642107450898887], ['as', 0.027434272056531227], ['To', 0.026810765873428243], ['our', 0.02504416502130313], ['are', 0.024628494232567806], ['But', 0.024420658838200146], ['all', 0.024316741141016316], ['What', 0.024212823443832486], ['shall', 0.024004988049464823], ['on', 0.02265405798607503], ['thee', 0.022134469500155875], ['Enter', 0.021822716408604385], ['thy', 0.021199210225501402], ['no', 0.020783539436766082], ['she', 0.02026395095084693], ['am', 0.02005611555647927], ['by', 0.019848280162111608], ['have', 0.019848280162111608]]
```

Instead of outputing the top 50 words of all three texts, its outputs the top 50 words of each text, 150 words. Im struggling on trying to delete the duplicates but add their ratios together. For example, in macbeth.txt the word 'the' has a ratio of 0.12929982922664066, allswell.txt has a ratio of 0.15813168261114238, and othello.txt has a ratio of 0.17894627455055595. I want to combine the ratios of all three of them. I;m pretty sure I have to use a for loop but I'm struggling to loop through a list within a list. I am more of a java guy so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for the ratio of word occurrence within each file individually, or ratio across all 3 files combined?  In other words - is the ratio for "the" supposed to be how often it occurs in each work separately (so it has 3 distinct ratios) or is it supposed to be the ratio of how often "the" occurs in all three texts combined (one value).

Comment: It's supposed to be how often "the" occurs in all three texts combined(one value) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay. It makes a difference in your logic then.  You can't just sum the three ratios together.  You have to take the number of times a word appears across all three files and then divide it by the sum of the total number of words in each file.  You need to think of the three individual files as one large file, and then do the math.  Which is what @phynfo's solution does for you.  @zmbq's solution works too.  All you need to do is move everything after `items = list(count.items())` out of your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're summarizing the count inside your loop over files. Move the summary code outside your for loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension and the Counter-class:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter([word  for file in ['macbeth.txt','allswell.txt','othello.txt'] 
                   for word in open(file).read().split()])
```

Then you get a dict which maps words to their counts. You can sort them like this:

```
sorted([(i,v) for v,i in c.items()])
```

If you want the relative quantities, then you can calculate the total number of words:

```
numWords = sum([i for (v,i) in c.items()])
```

and adapt the dict `c` via a dict-comprehension:

```
c = { v:(i/numWords) for (v,i) in c.items()}
```